# Graceful alternative to map a Future[Option[...]]

Tags: scala

I have 2 methods that return `Future[Option[String]]` and need to invoke the second method if the first method returns a `Future[None]`. Following is the code I have so far:

```
def method1(): Future[Option[String]] = Future(None)
def method2(): Future[Option[String]] = Future(Some("test"))

val resultFuture = method1().flatMap(option =>
if (option.isDefined) { // Alternatives?
  Future(option)
} else {
  method2()
})

val durationSeconds = {
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import scala.language.postfixOps
  20 seconds
}
val result = Await.result(resultFuture, durationSeconds)
println(result) // Prints Some(test) as expected
```

I think this solution is deficient because

1. The success value (the if portion) is being mapped although there is no actual value transformation
2. Un-necessary creation of a second Future(in the if block) to keep the compiler happy.

I have tried

1. `method1().flatMap(option => option.fold(method2)(value => Future(Option(value))))`. But this has the same issue.
2. `option.orElse(...)`, but it needs to return an `Option[B]` *not* `Future[Option[B]]`.

Appreciate any pointers on mapping the `Future[None]` without explicitly mapping/passing-through the `Future[Some[String]]`.

Comment: Slightly related: check out https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Future.apply` creates a new future and schedules it to run on the execution context, which is indeed costly, so you're right it's not the best solution.

Instead of `Future.apply` you could just use `Future.sucessful`, which creates already resolved `Future` and is a very cheap operation. You could also make your code (arguably) more readable with pattern matching and for-comprehension:

```
for{
    m1 <- method1()
    result <- m1 match {
      case x @ Some(_) => Future.successful(x) //just lifts value into Future context
      case None => method2()
   }
} yield result
```

You could also use a flat map with pattern matching:

```
method1().flatMap{
   case x @ Some(_) => Future.successful(x)
   case None => method2()
}
```

Another solution you might consider is using monad transformer `OptionT` which simplifies operations on nested monad stack like `Future[Option[T]]`. Both [scalaz](https://www.47deg.com/blog/fp-for-the-average-joe-part-2-scalaz-monad-transformers/) and [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html) provide its own implementations of `OptionT`. Below an example with `cats`:

```
import cats.data.OptionT
import cats.implicits._

OptionT(method1()).orElseF(method2()).value
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one alternative.

```
val resultFuture :Future[Option[String]] = method1().flatMap(
  _.fold(method2())(str => Future.successful(Some(str))))
```

It still re-wraps the populated `Option` but there's less overhead as a `Future.successful()`.